# Affect of Content Deployment on Caching

Tags: architecture, caching, fragment

we are working on a website with three tier architecture. And the content store is a File System which contains the static content like images and all. We have two types of pages which contain static content and dynamic content but on the whole the page rendering is dynamic. 
The question is what will be the affect of accessing the File System from the presentation layer or the business layer on the caching mechanisms if we use Data Caching or Fragment Caching or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static content such as images, css or javascript will be served up from the filesystem. Data Caching and Fragment Caching will only affect the produced markup.

Comment: So, does this mean that accessing the File System irrespective of the layer will not affect the caching mechanisms?